# Item (Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document) with the same ID "2" already exists

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, orders, sales-order

I cleared my test orders from Magento 2 with these steps:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37861046/how-to-remove-test-orders-from-magento2

However when I go to Sales->Orders at first it works. But after I create my second order the page gives an error msg:

```
Item (Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document) with the same ID "2" already exists.
```

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue today, it was due to **3rd party** `extensions/modules` adding attributes to the orders. I didn't truncate those tables on the first run, that's why we were seeing the issue. As soon as I did that, everything went back to normal.

Make sure there aren't any other `extensions/modules` creating attributes that are related to orders, or tables that are referencing the orders.